# Gitlab deployment_tier purpose?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, development-environment

Hello can anybody tell me what exactly the `deployment_tier` for `environments` is for in gitlab-ci?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#environmentdeployment_tier
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#deployment-tier-of-environments

Is this just like a label for the environment or does it actually has any functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used primarily for VSA analytics and DORA metrics features of GitLab. By default, GitLab only counts "production" deployments in its metrics and analytics. GitLab determines whether a deployment is "production" or not by the `name:` of the environment. Basically, if your environment is named "production" or `production/*` it will be considered a production deployment.

However, some GitLab users may prefer to use a different environment name, such as `us-east-1` or whatever for their production environments, but they still want these deployments to be included in the VSA analytics and DORA metrics as "production" deployments. This is where `deployment_tier` comes in. By setting the `deployment_tier` to `production` you can have environments not following the naming pattern to be considered in your VSA analytics and DORA metrics.

TL;DR yes, it is just a label and, aside from metrics/analytics, it does not otherwise materially affect functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Aother usage, introduced by [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#fetch-secrets-based-on-deployment-tier) (July 2022)

> ### Fetch secrets based on deployment tier
>
> Secrets can be assigned based on the deployment tier of an environment. In this release, we include the `deployment_tier` in the JSON Web Token (`CI_JOB_JWT`) so that users can fetch secrets per a specific deployment tier.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363590).