# Which environment names are mapped to deployment_tier "production" in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to use the Gitlab built-in CI/CD analytics. For this feature i need to map our deployment jobs to the `deployment_tier: production` as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/ci_cd_analytics.html#view-dora-deployment-frequency-chart). When I further looked into the documentation I found the following sentence:

> By default, GitLab assumes a tier based on the environment name. Instead, you can use the deployment_tier keyword to specify a tier.

What I didn't found however was how exactly GitLab assumes the deployment tier. On another [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71253812/7580352) someone stated that it is only mapped on `production` and `production/*`. But I also found that environment names like `prod` are mapped to this deployment tier. This currently causes our CI/CD analytics to show wrong values, because we have multiple other jobs that use environment name `prod`. An obvious solution would be to either don`t use the environment at all on these job or to map them to another deployment tier. However I was wondering if anyone has some insights on what exactly happens this deployment tier assumption process, because it is very intransparent at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the deployment_tier associated with your environments via API
The API is

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/environments
```

Edit the url with your GitLabURL and replace projectID in url.

This will give a json response for all environments. Below is a snippet

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "dev",
    "slug": "dev",
    "external_url": "https://urlofyourenvironment",
    "created_at": "2023-12-07T19:57:43.679Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-12-12T13:10:43.962Z",
    "tier": "development",
    "project": {
        "id": 11111
    }
}
```

As you can see it says `"tier": "development"`, because we have configured this attribute for dev env in gitlab yaml file, within environment section as below

```
environment:
    deployment_tier: development
    on_stop: stop-dev
```

For other environments where we don't explicitly provided deployment_tier, GitLab assumed the deployment_tier and logic is not explanatory.

For env named **stage** it picked tier as **staging**
For env named **sit** and **uat**, it picked tier as **other**

My suggestion is don't provide the environment section on all jobs except the jobs which does the `deploy` and `undeploy` (if applicable) operations